# Customized content assist for Java in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, customization, content-assist

I'd like to implement a customized content assist (aka. auto-completion) for my Java API's and custom jsp tags. Basically, I'd like to set the advisory level (discouraged use) on the undocumented features.
(Of course, the proper way is to expose api's through a facade. However, it's way to late for that and the only way is damage control).

What is the proper way to implement customized content assist for Java/JSP as part of an existing plugin?

Many thanks,
Val

Answer (score 1):

You could try 
[access rules](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t53736.html)

Comment: Thanks for that reply. Not quite what I was looking for, but it'll come in handy if I don't find anything else. Ideally I would like to put up a warning in the content assist dropdown (access rules seems to only underline the already completed command).